# Really big SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I want to ask if is there any faster method how to make this query? Actually it takes about 100 seconds to finish. I have about 10 000 000 (1 GB) rows in a table. This is the statistics generating script.

This is the query:

```
  $results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hawkeye WHERE player_id='".$playerID."'") or die("MYSQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```

And then the php code:

```
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($results)
  if($row["action"] == 4){$commandcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 3){$chatcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 1){$placedcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 0){$breakcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 5){$joincount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 6){$quitcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 7){$qteleportcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 12){$pvpdeathcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 21){$mobkillcount++;}
  else if($row["action"] == 22){$otherdeathcount++;}
  else {}
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Do you really need to select all 10 000 000 rows at once? Why?

Comment: get rid of * from your query right away. Target the columns you want, and even if you want them all it will be quicker not to use *.

Comment: Let me guess: there's no index on the `player_id` field, right?

Comment: @Pekka because it's for statistics.

Comment: By the way, I like that `else{}` part, it nicely imitates the behavior of `default` section within `switch` - which is obviously not used for some important reasons.

Comment: It might be possible to do those statistics directly inside mySQL. That would save a lot of traffic

Comment: @JoeGreen Why is that? Doesn't * just translate to all columns?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use MYSQL to do the math for you. It's faster then PHP:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS action_count
     , action
FROM hawkeye 
WHERE player_id='".$playerID."'"
GROUP BY action

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['action'] . ': ' . $row['action_count'] . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Also make sure player_id is indexed

Comment: @Mato Kormuth: 1) John Conde is correct - if you *can* do something in SQL, then you *should* do it in SQL.  It's *much* more efficient.  2) raina77ow is also correct.  You should have an index for player_id on hawkeye.  If you don't already, the lack of index is very possibly the entire problem.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is indexed, it will still need to read through 10M records to get a COUNT, this is fine if it is just a single request for a single person.  It will not perform well.

Comment: @CraigTrombly: of course the index matters: you only want to go through the records that match the condition `player_id=?`. More importantly, don't put the value directly in the query string like this (`'".$playerID."'`): use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections (or at the very least, use `mysql_real_escape_string`).

Comment: @Bruno mysql_real_escape_string is done before the mysql query ;)

Comment: Thank you now it takes about 2 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
SELECT action, count(*) FROM hawkeye WHERE player_id='$playerID' GROUP BY action
```

So you will cycle only once per **action type**, not once per **action**

Comment: There's only one row fetched in the original code. But in general your answer is very nice, +1. )

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to do some calculations.  Trying looking into doing aggregates and or using an analytic database like infobright which stores the aggregates in memory.  Avoid do the SELECT * and do an actual SELECT column1, column2.  Mostly though read into doing aggregates like SUM, COUNT Group BY and Order By.

Answer (score 1):

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT action, count(*) as `cnt` FROM hawkeye WHERE player_id='".$playerID."' GROUP BY action") or die("MYSQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  if($row["action"] == 4){$commandcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 3){$chatcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 1){$placedcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 0){$breakcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 5){$joincount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 6){$quitcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 7){$qteleportcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 12){$pvpdeathcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 21){$mobkillcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else if($row["action"] == 22){$otherdeathcount=$row["cnt"];}
  else {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an index to the hawkeye table that indexes by `player_id` and also follow John Conde's suggestion.